# Sparse subset of a vector space and entanglement

Tags: quantum-information

Could any one tell me concrete mathematical definition of sparse subset of a vector space. I am not understanding this [image: entanglement]

Comment: The right way to go about this is not to post the snipped out image, but rather, say "_Quoting verbatim from the text (title) by (author)_ ...", then block quote the text. After that, post the exact point of doubt/clarification sought. Cheers :)

Comment: "sparse" is not a commonly used term for states (or sets), but I guess it means the set is not [*dense*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set).

Comment: "sparse" usually (and here) means something like negligibly small w.r.t. the ambient set: measure or volume zero, lower dimensional, infinite index, etc

Comment: Please don't write clearly vague or vaguely clear comments. If you don't have eyes just to confirm you that I wanted concrete mathematical ideas or examples not your wise advice